# .htaccess rule to exclude a specific folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have an .htacces a rule like this:

```
   RewriteRule !\.(png|gif|JPG|jpg|...|txt|html|xclx|css|js|ico)$ index.php
```

and I need to exclude one folder from this. How does the Condition to do this look like?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, can you edit your question and describe more exactly what you're trying to achieve? The way it looks to me is that files that end with the defined types, such as `.bmp` are redirected to index.php, so therefore standard foldernames would not be affected by this. Can you edit and make the question clearer? Thank you.

Comment: And seach SO for similar questions, I'm sure this will have been answered already, if you can find the correct terminology to search for. . .

Comment: A rewriteCond needs to be added to this specific rule. I dont know htaccess good enough and I cant find the code for this specific rule. The search and tryout process would take forever, so i hope that someone that knows htacces will answer this.

Comment: You need a `RewriteCond` before this rule

Comment: When I use this rule and I type in addressbar a folder name for example "http://domain.com/foldername", then it would redirect me to the content of "http://domain.com/index.php", in the addressbar it would still show "http://domain.com/foldername". I need from you that I can exclude foldername from this behavior and that it will instead send me to the index file of foldername.